# 404 No input file specified. on VirtualBox, CentOS 6.5, Nginx

Tags: linux, macos, virtualbox, centos, nginx

I have installed `VirtualBox` on my mac, and change the `settings` with VitualBox , `Adapter 1 - Attached to: Host-only Adapter, Name: vboxnet0`.
and install guest addistions
`./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`
‘Settings’ > 'Shared Folders’ > 'Add a new share folder definition.’ > 'auto-mount'

When I visit `domain1.com.localhost` shows `No input file specified..` I do check the folder exist seems mount success,
and I check access.log shows `404`, so I doubt does the folder `/media/sf_Sites` permission wrong?  or something I miss??

ls -l /media/sf_Sites

```
drwxrwx---. 1 root vboxsf  domain1.com
```

vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user nginx;
```

vi /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name domain1.com.localhost www.domain1.com.localhost
  access_log /var/log/nginx/domain1.com.access.log;
  root /media/sf_Sites/domain1.com;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

  location /robots.txt {
    alias /media/sf_Sites/domain1.com/app/robots.txt;
  }

  location ^/(images/|javascripts) {
    root /media/sf_Sites/domain1.com/app/assets;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_buffers 8 32k;
  }
}
```

on my mac
sudo vi /etc/hosts

```
192.168.56.101 domain1.com.localhost
```

**UPDATE**

I mount the folder to /var/www/html/

```
mkdir /var/www/html/Sites
mount -t vboxsf Sites -o rw,dmode=777,gid=0,uid=0 /var/www/html/Sites
```

and change nginx config `root /var/www/html/Sites` and try
`domain1.com.localhost` I got `403 Forbidden`,
`domain1.com.localhost/info.php` `No input file specified` 
`domain1.com.localhost/index.html` `No input file specified`

`ls -l /var/www/html/Sites`

-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  index.html
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  info.php
drwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  domain1.com

but if I create file as loggedin virtualbox root user create file index.html under `/var/www/html/index.html` and change nginx config root , then I can visit the file...

Why???

I also treid change nginx user 
`vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`
`user nginx; > user root;`

still not work...